# Eclipse + PHP development/build/deployment environment setup

Tags: php, eclipse, deployment, build-process

I'm new to PHP development and was wondering if an automated build/deploy cycle is easy to set up. What I'm thinking is having the PHP project inside Eclipse and being able to start a test instance on a remote test server which I will be controlling from within Eclipse (server start/stop). Also, upon saving changes having them automatically deployed on the server (in a manner similar to jvm's hot deploy). Debugging that remote test server would also be nice! The reason I am thinking of doing this to a remote machine instead of the local one is to have different team members accessing that server in turns from their own PCs.

Please note I am interested in the technicalities of setting up a test environment to assist development not a workflow for deployment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My 2 cents: not a very good idea to have a central server with everybody access in turn (especially in each people has the right to stop/start the server). A better way is a local server for every one and a source versioning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is meant for testing specific features. An svn repo is available already. This is to be used selectively on a standard setup.

Comment: maybe a central server with the same config as production environment and an separated account / vhost for every  developer. But only as a second instance, after local webserver.

Comment: I was hoping for some advice on how to actually do the remote deployment/debugging. It's not going to be used from more than a couple of people and it would help if resources could be reused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would slow down development way to much. It's much more efficent if each member have their own local webserver they can test on.

Introducing a shared server would open up to a lot of problems, for example, how would you handle situations where two members test their code at the same time? You do not want to upload your changes everytime you save a file, that's a lot of wasted time for just data transfer.

I would recommend setting up a continious integration environment with [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) and pull your repo at a given interval. This can trigger a test run and verify your code. This way, you'll get notified when your code is broken, and who broke it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply alexn. However, this is meant to help in reusing resources among a couple of developers without having to setup the entire env on each machine.

Comment: I see, what do your devs need to do in order to set up their environment for your project?

Comment: Setup apache http, php, mysql, etc which are rather superfluous in this case.